# Get the right number of a value in SQL Server using substring

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have this data in my SQL Server:

```
1/2
1/4
2/23
12/13
1/10
...
```

I need to change these to `002,004,023,013,010,..`

I just need to select the end (RIGHT) part number of my value. I got the LEFT part using this code before:

```
RIGHT('000' + LEFT(SheetNumber, CHARINDEX('/', SheetNumber) - 1), 3)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT Right('000' + RIGHT(SheetNumber,LEN(SheetNumber) - CHARINDEX('/',SheetNumber) ), 3)
```

OR

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE(@SheetNumber,'/','/000'),3)
```

Comment: Plus1  I like your second options.  Elegant.

Comment: same here. The second option is really nice

Answer (score 3):

Your were almost there

```
Declare @YourTable table (SheetNumber varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('1/2'),
('1/4'),
('2/23'),
('12/13'),
('1/10')

Select right('000'+substring(SheetNumber,CHARINDEX('/',SheetNumber) + 1,10),3)
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
(No column name)
002
004
023
013
010
```

Comment: Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to get the right part like this :

```
declare @table table (SheetNumber varchar(10))
insert into @table values ('1/2')
insert into @table values ('2/23')

select Right(SheetNumber, len(SheetNumber) - CHARINDEX('/',SheetNumber)) from @table
```

This will give you this :

```
2
23
```

Now build on this to pad 0 in front of it

```
declare @table table (SheetNumber varchar(10))
insert into @table values ('1/2')
insert into @table values ('2/23')

select Right('000' + Right(SheetNumber, len(SheetNumber) - CHARINDEX('/',SheetNumber)), 3) from @table
```

and that will give you this :

```
002
023
```